# Write SQL query and get values for given range using <= (or) between and (or) any other

Tags: sql, range, between

```
create table demo4 
(
    sno int, 
    fromvalue int, 
    tovalue int
)

insert into demo4 
values (1, 2002, 2002), (2, 2003, 2003), (3, 2004, 2004), (4, 2001, 2010),
       (5, 2006, 2007), (6, 2011, 2011), (7, 2005, 2005), (8, 2006, 2010),
       (9, 2006, 2011), (10, 2008, 2009)


            |sno   |fromvalue |tovalue|
            +------+----------+-------+
            |  1   | 2002     |  2002 |
            |  2   | 2003     |  2003 |
            |  3   | 2004     |  2004 |
            |  4   | 2001     |  2010 |
            |  5   | 2006     |  2007 |
            |  6   | 2011     |  2011 |
            |  7   | 2005     |  2005 |
            |  8   | 2006     |  2010 |
            |  9   | 2006     |  2011 |
            | 10   | 2008     |  2009 |
```

From above table, I want to get `sno` values as 1,2,3,4 for given range 2002-2004 as from value and tovalue

I tried with following queries, but it doesn't work

```
select * 
from demo2 
where (fromvalue between 2002 and 2004) 
   or (tovalue between 2002 and 2004)   

-- 1, 2, 3 are fetched (4 is not fetched)

select * 
from demo2 
where 2002 <= fromvalue 
  and tovalue <= 2004 

-- 1, 2, 3 are fetched (4 is not fetched)
```

Comment: what have you tried by yourself ?

Comment: I tried with:

select * from demo2 where (fromvalue between 2020 and 2004) or (tovalue between 2002 and 2004)
select *  from dem02 where 2022<=fromvalue and tovalue<=2004

Comment: Show the actual result for each of your attempts and explain exactly why your result does not meet your requirement.  Also, why is 4 one of your expected results?  Is 2001 or 2010 between 2002 and 2004??

Comment: (4, 2001, 2010) **is not an expected result**, since neither 2001 nor 2010 is between 2002 and 2004!!  Did you ask the reverse question??

Comment: @JonArmstrong As 2002 and 2004 are present in 2001(fromvalue) and 2010(tovalue) so it needs to be in the result set

Comment: _for given range 2002-2004 as from value and tovalue_ ... Neither 2001 nor 2010 is between those _from_ and _to_ values.  I believe you stated the wrong question.

Comment: If you meant to ask, "find all the `sno` ranges which contain any values from 2002 through 2004", use @Serg solution.  But you didn't ask that question, so I can't exactly upvote @Serg solution yet.  It appears to represent your intended question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want interval intersection (overlapping)

```
select * 
from demo4 
where fromvalue <= 2004 and tovalue >= 2002
```

For a 2001-2010 interval it will be

```
select * 
from demo4 
where fromvalue <= 2010 and tovalue >= 2001;
```

Generally, the intervals `s1 - e1` and `s2 - e2` overlapp condition is `s1<=e2 and s2<=e1` So for `fromvalue - tovalue` and `2001 - 2010` it is exactly `fromvalue <= 2010 and 2001 <= tovalue`.

Comment: If I consider ur query then for range 2001-2010  I am getting only  (sno:4)
but i need to get 1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10 (i.e all values exept 6)

Comment: @ChaitanyaReddy, no  you'll get exactly what you need.